# Making MakeFile for Curl in VSCode

Tags: c++, c, linux, curl, makefile

I am trying to make a MakeFile for linking Curl, but I cannot find a good source to learn and implement my MakeFile, following is what I have written for my MakeFile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -Wall

BIN=~/Documents/Github/Covid-Visualizer/testing

all: $(BIN)

%: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -lcurl
```

and following is the code for my testing project:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <curl/curl.h> 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    CURL *curl=curl_easy_init();

    if(!curl)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"init failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // set options
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jacobsorber.com");

    // perform actions
    CURLcode result=curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(result!=CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "download problem \n");
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am expecting the following from this MakeFile:

```
g++ -g -Wall test.cpp -o test.out -lcurl
```

But I assume due to wrong implementation I am getting the following error when I use `make test` :

```
g++     test.cpp   -o test
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc5miClt.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: test] Error 1
```

Following is the output for `make -r test`:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.
```

Additional Information-

Platform: Linux

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ Maybe you need to replace `%: %.cpp` with `%.o: %.cpp`.

Comment: It seems that the built-in rule is being chosen over your custom one. This makefile however does not reproduce the issue for me, are you sure it's a complete example? You may also want to run `make -r test` to see if it works then.

Comment: Even after changing the MakeFile I am still getting this `g++     test.cpp   -o test ` as my build instructions .

Comment: Have you tried `make -r test`? What does it tell you then? Also, can you share `make --version` output?

Comment: @raspy I tried `make -r test` and it gives this error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.`
and this is the output for `make --version`: GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: This means that the rule you have in your Makefile is invalid, as it doesn't get matched when there are no built-in rules. Are you absolutely sure that the Makefile you posted is the same Makefile you run? In my environment the one you posted works correctly. Please update your question of `make -dr test` output.

Comment: Yes, its the same MakeFile

Comment: Please remember that when dealing with software, exact details are absolutely everything.  In your message you sometimes say `Makefile` and you sometimes say `MakeFile`.  Those are **two totally different files**.  Which one is the real name of your makefile?  Please be sure to only use the real name, not some other incorrect name.  make will only look for `Makefile` by default, not `MakeFile`.

Comment: @MadScientist My bad, I corrected all the wrong occurrences to MakeFile. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, well, that's your problem.  As I said, make will only look for makefiles named `Makefile` (or `makefile` or, if you're using GNU make, `GNUmakefile`) by default.  You have named your makefile `MakeFile`.  So make is not reading that file.  So none of your rules or recipes are available.

You should either rename your makefile to be `Makefile` (or one of the other options above), or else you have to tell make what the name of your makefile is with the `-f` option:

```
make -f MakeFile test
```